# How to display reqs/sec in the rails logger log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

The following log line in Rails log is common.

```
Completed in 0.13425 (7 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.03244 (29%) | DB: ).0863 (65%) | 200 OK [htt://localhost/reviews]
```

But in my development log file, I see the whole line except the (7 reqs/sec) part.
Why this reqs/sec is not shown in my log?? How can I make it appear??

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty useless in the development log as the development process is much heavier than production. This is due to the fact that classes are loaded once and then cached in production, whereas in development classes are reloaded on every request. This overhead means that any measurement of requests per second is not at all representative of what it would be in production.

Comment: @Steve, Thanks for the reply and the notes.
But what if I still want to have that in my dev log file?
Do you know how to coz I've seen that in RailsCasts screencasts in dev log. I need to know how to do it??